# Get Values from Web API Owin Token in Angular 2/5

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2, token, claims

I'm fairly new in Angular still trying to learn every aspect of it.
Right now i'm facing a problem reading a claim sent in my access_token from a WEB API, just to clear things out my angular app is working fine can get the encrypted token and send post with Bearer authorization, but what if i want to read a claim which is the current **status** of my user and based on the status i can show a clearer Message to the users.

So is there anywhere i can read the claims in angular or some other ways to make it work ? All i need is to get the status of the logged user the moment the user submits username and password.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: In your backend you create an object containing the claims (or only the claim you need preferably) and return it as json either as part of the login process, or as a separate API call

Comment: Thank you for your reply devzero,i already have the claim inside the token, but it's sent encrypted to the angular, i need to decrypt it somehow to be able to read the values, if i do a separate API call after Login i wouldnt let the user know if the account is blocked or w/e status it's in.

Comment: I still think you should just decrypt it on the server and return the claim and the token in the first web api request